# Wireless Distribution assistance

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-bridge, wds

Preface:  I have a holiday home that has wireless internet access provided by the site.  There is no hardwired connection available.

To access the internet the provider usually requires that you input a key via a browser.  This key expires and a new key is provided every 7 days.

The provider has allowed the MAC address of my TV through their system to always connect and not require this key.

Question:  Is it possible for me to replace that TV with a router that could spoof the MAC address of the TV and serve other devices within the home to allow them to connect to the internet?  If so, could you recommend a product/products that could accomplish the task?

Comment: Most of the standard consumer wireless routers like Linksys that I have seen have as part of the options the ability to spoof a MAC address. I have not actually used that functionality but when I connect to the router with a web browser to review the settings and menus I remember seeing a MAC address spoofing page. That said, your provider may object to you using this procedure as it may be viewed as against the user agreement and terms of service by the provider.

Comment: Your provider knows the content being accessed by a TV and probably has filters in place, only for that type of traffic.  They will wonder why traffic that is not supposed to be accessed by a TV is being accessed from that MAC address.  Furthermore, they also know that a TV generates a certain amount of traffic.  With your multiple devices connected behind a NAT'ed router, that will also raise a red flag because the traffic volume from that MAC addr will go up.  If your wireless signal is weak, you're only option is to complain and have them install an Access Point inside your holiday home.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond but the question is specifically about the feasibility of implementing the solution and the hardware recommendations for that solution.  

If we could track this back to the original question it would be useful.

Comment: @LeeW - Yeah... Have a ball and don't hurt yourself. https://www.linksys.com/ca/support-article?articleNum=142912

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Linksys router by changing MAC address through web browser provisioning interface.

Comment: So you’re now stating with certainty that Linksys routers provide this capability? Have you ever used it?  (I ask because eight hours ago you said that you hadn’t.) All Linksys routers, or just some? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @Scott MAC address spoofing is a fairly standard thing for consumer routers such as the Linksys model I have in my lab. My students have used it. I have no idea as to model numbers or anything. Google it.